# Why does it say input data array is not in correct format fro jqchart?

Tags: javascript, vb.net, jqchart

My data is in this format as belwo;

i.e mymy= UnitedStates,65|UnitedKingdom,58|Germany,30|India,60|Russia,65|China,75

Code :

```
            var myarr = mymy.split("|");
            var i=0;
            var myarr2 = [];
            for (i=0;i<myarr.length;i++)
            {
            var mytemp=myarr[i].split(",");
              myarr2[i]=mytemp[0]+','+mytemp[1];
            };
             var myChart = new JSChart('chartcontainer','bar');
             var myData2 = new Array(myarr2);
                   /* 
                   where mow 
                    myarr2[0]={UnitedStates,65}
                    myarr2[1]={UnitedKingdom,58}
                    and so on 

                   */
              myChart.setDataArray(myData2);                
              myChart.draw();
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like dataArray has to be an array of data points, each being an array having label and value as members. So I guess it'd be:

```
var mymy = 'UnitedStates,65|UnitedKingdom,58|Germany,30|India,60|Russia,65|China,75'
var myarr = mymy.split("|");
var myarr2 = [];
for(i=0;i<myarr.length;i++){
    var mytemp=myarr[i].split(",");
    myarr2[i] = [mytemp[0],mytemp[1]];
};
var myChart = new JSChart('chartcontainer','bar');

myChart.setDataArray(myarr2);                
myChart.draw();
```

Comment: It still says , 
JSChart: Input data in wrong format for selected chart type